# Как выяснить дату последней модификации элемента (статьи, товара, новости) в Битрикс ?

Tags: php, cms, битрикс

Как выяснить дату последней модификации элемента (статьи, товара, новости) в Битрикс ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходимо вывести дату модификации элемента, то в шаблоне, который использует элемент, необходимо добавить

```
<? echo $arResult["TIMESTAMP_X"]; ?>
```

или

```
<?=$arResult["TIMESTAMP_X"]?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно при помощи функции [CIBlockElement::GetByID](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getbyid.php) получить необходимый элемент по его ID и в полях полученного элемента получить поле [TIMESTAMP_X](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/fields.php#felement) в нем то и храниться дата последнего изменения.